# Material-UI: X-Grid / DataGrid Default ColumnMenu Not Showing

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui, mui-datatable

I'm implementing the x-grid on my project, and the ColumnMenu is not showing when the 3dots are clicked:
[popup not displaying when 3-dots are clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjXVK.png)

Based on the documentation it appears the default behaviour of the ColumnMenu is to appear on a click event.

The event is getting fired because I was able to capture it in a `console.log`. It has made me wonder if the dependencies are not met for the x-grid. However I have the latest version of x-grid and very new version of the core package. Below is a snippet from my yarn.lock:

```
"@material-ui/x-grid@^4.0.0-alpha.20":
  version "4.0.0-alpha.20"
  dependencies:
    "@material-ui/utils" "^5.0.0-alpha.14"
    "@material-ui/x-license" "^4.0.0-alpha.20"
    prop-types "^15.7.2"
    reselect "^4.0.0"

"@material-ui/core@^4.1.1":
  version "4.11.0"
  dependencies:
    "@babel/runtime" "^7.4.4"
    "@material-ui/styles" "^4.10.0"
    "@material-ui/system" "^4.9.14"
    "@material-ui/types" "^5.1.0"
    "@material-ui/utils" "^4.10.2"
    "@types/react-transition-group" "^4.2.0"
    clsx "^1.0.4"
    hoist-non-react-statics "^3.3.2"
    popper.js "1.16.1-lts"
    prop-types "^15.7.2"
    react-is "^16.8.0"
    react-transition-group "^4.4.0"
```

My project is currently running **react** & **react-dom** **v.16.13.1**, which mets the minimum requirement for @material-ui/core

This what my x-grid currently looks like:

```
         <XGrid
          rows={rows}
          columns={columns}
          rowHeight={38}
          checkboxSelection
          hideFooterSelectedRowCount
          page={page}
          pageSize={rowsPerPage}
          pagination
          paginationMode="server"
          components={{
            Toolbar: () => (
              <XGridToolbar
                title="Titles"
                rowsSelected={selectedRows.length}
                onToolbarDeleteClick={setDeleteDialogOpen}
                onToolbarEditClick={this.handleEditClick}
              />
            ),
          }}
          onSelectionModelChange={this.handleSelectedRows}
          sortingMode="server"
          sortModel={orderBy}
          onSortModelChange={this.handleHeaderClick}
          onPageChange={this.handlePageChange}
          onPageSizeChange={this.handleRowsPerPageChange}
          rowsPerPageOptions={defaultRowsPerPageOptions}
          rowCount={totalCount}
        />
```

I've tried manually setting the ColumnMenu in the `components` prop to the default `GridColumnMenu` but I had no luck. I've also tried removing all my modifications and trying to get it to work with the just the `columns` and `rows` props provided but that didn't work either.

Also, when I used the default `Toolbar` the icons would appear, however when clicked they wouldn't bring up the panel either.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is this a dependency issue?

Thanks for any help in advance! I've been searching for the answer everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: The issue was that the z-index was being inherited from our  component. I didn't think to look there originally, because this hasn't effect any other popover or snack bar.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a duplicate of https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/issues/946. But hard to tell as not minimal live reproduction was provided.

Comment: It's similar but different. I've tested by removing all of the props except for `rows` and `columns` and the ColumnMenu still doesn't work:  ```<XGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} />```